# Is there a way to detect the pixels of a sprite for a collision in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

It doesn't have to be pixel-perfect collision, but I want it to be as close as possible to the actual pixels of the sprite. FYI, I created a 32 by 32 sprite but then I was only able to fill estimately half the amount of pixels, so the rest is just transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most games out there don't use anything close to pixel perfect collision and it's usually not needed. Having some approximated rectangle or a combination of multiple rectangles is usually enough.

SFML itself provides `intersects()` and `contains()` functions for it's `sf::Rect<T>` class.

There's also some collision detection class in the [SFML wiki](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Source%3A-Simple-Collision-Detection-for-SFML-2) which also features a bit-mask collision, that's basically a pixel-perfect collision detection.